# There's more than one type of multipath

Tags: discussion, tags

I edited this question today as I monitor all the "multipath" tagged questions.

[Concurrent Multipath Transfer over SCTP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462712/concurrent-multipath-transfer-over-sctp)

multipath tag has always referred to the storage domain, even says so in the tag description.

However there is clearly multipath support for networking.

Should we begin to disambiguate the tagging e.g. multipath -> storage-multipath and create
network-multipath or stick with the status quo?

We have any easy way to bulk rename tags right?

Comment: Unfortunately we have no easy way to bulk real questions. The best we can do is blacklist multipath and force people to choose either multipath-network or multipath-storage.

Comment: And that was supposed to be retag not real..

Comment: @Seth There are only 5 questions tagged multipath, I think we can retag those.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi good, /me didn't check.

Comment: yeah, I think I had serverfault in mind when I wrote that which has 72 questions tagged as multipath.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a tag that means different things on different context, then a disambiguation is necessary, unclear tags are not OK. There isn't almost no double meaning tags that would be useful for us. If you want, the tag to be renamed and another for other cases created. There ain't that many instances of those so retagging it yourself should be fine.